# Formatting a number by a decimal

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, split

I'm trying to transform an array of numbers such that each number has only one nonzero digit. 
so basically

```
"7970521.5544"
```

will give me

```
 ["7000000", "900000", "70000", "500", "20", "1", ".5", ".05", ".004", ".0004"]
```

I tried:

```
  var j = "7970521.5544"

  var k =j.replace('.','')

  var result = k.split('')

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(parseFloat(Math.round(result[i] * 10000) /10).toFixed(10))
}
```

Any ideas, I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: You’re losing the position of the decimal place when you do `replace('.','')`. I would suggest instead using `split('.')` first, then processing the integer and fractional parts separately

Answer (score 4):

### Algorithm:

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the number in two parts using the decimal notation.

Run a for loop to multiply each digit with the corresponding power of `10`, like:

```
value = value * Math.pow(10, index); // for digits before decimal
value = value * Math.pow(10, -1 * index); // for digits after decimal
```

Then, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the non-zero elements and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enate both the arrays. (remember to re-[reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the left-side array)

```js
var n = "7970521.5544"

var arr = n.split('.'); // '7970521' and '5544'
var left = arr[0].split('').reverse(); // '1250797'
var right = arr[1].split(''); // '5544'

for(let i = 0; i < left.length; i++)
  left[i] = (+left[i] * Math.pow(10, i) || '').toString();

for(let i = 0; i < right.length; i++) 
  right[i] = '.' + +right[i] * Math.pow(10, -i);

let res = left.reverse() // reverses the array
  .filter(n => !!n) 
// ^^^^^^ filters those value which are non zero
  .concat(right.filter(n => n !== '.0'));
// ^^^^^^ concatenation
  
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This includes "0", as well the leading "0" in decimals both of which are different than the OP desired result. The output is also one place off in the decimals: `5` instead of `.5`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `padStart` and `padEnd` combined with `reduce()` to build the array. The amount you want to pad will be the index of the decimal minus the index in the loop for items left of the decimal and the opposite on the right.

Using `reduce()` you can make a new array with the padded strings taking care to avoid the zeroes and the decimal itself.

```js
let s = "7970521.5544"
let arr = s.split('')
let d_index = s.indexOf('.')
if (d_index == -1) d_index = s.length  // edge case for nums with no decimal

let nums = arr.reduce((arr, n, i) => {
  if (n == 0 || i == d_index) return arr
  arr.push((i < d_index) 
      ? n.padEnd(d_index - i, '0')
      : '.' + n.padStart(i - d_index, '0'))
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` your string and then utilize `Array.prototype.reduce` method. Take note of the decimal position and then just pad your value with `"0"` accordingly. Something like below:

```js
var s = "7970521.5544";
var original = s.split('');
var decimalPosition = original.indexOf('.');
var placeValues = original.reduce((accum, el, idx) => {
  var f = el;
  if (idx < decimalPosition) {
    for (let i = idx; i < (decimalPosition - 1); i++) {
      f += "0";
    }
    accum.push(f);
  } else if (idx > decimalPosition) {
    let offset = Math.abs(decimalPosition - idx) - 2;
    for (let i = 0; i <= offset; i++) {
      f = "0" + f;
    }
    f = "." + f;
    accum.push(f);
  }
  return accum;
}, []);

console.log(placeValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter alternative (doesn't work in IE) :

```js
var s = "7970521.5544"
var i = s.split('.')[0].length

var a = [...s].reduce((a, c) => (i && +c && a.push(i > 0 ?
     c.padEnd(i, 0) : '.'.padEnd(-i, 0) + c), --i, a), [])

console.log( a )
```

---

IE version :

```js
var s = "7970521.5544"
var i = s.split('.')[0].length

var a = [].reduce.call(s, function(a, c) { return (i && +c && a.push(i > 0 ?
        c + Array(i).join(0) : '.' + Array(-i).join(0) + c), --i, a); }, [])

console.log( a )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function standardToExpanded(n) {
    return String(String(Number(n))
        .split(".")
        .map(function(n, i) {
            // digits, decimals..
            var v = n.split("");
            // reverse decimals..
            v = i ? v.reverse() : v;
            v = v
                .map(function(x, j) {
                    // expanded term..
                    return Number([x, n.slice(j + 1).replace(/\d/g, 0)].join(""));
                })
                .filter(Boolean); // omit zero terms
            // unreverse decimals..
            v = i ? v.map(function(x) { 
                return '.' + String(x).split('').reverse().join('') 
            }).reverse() : v;
            return v;
        })).split(',');
}
console.log(standardToExpanded("7970521.5544"));
// -> ["7000000", "900000", "70000", "500", "20", "1", ".5", ".05", ".004", ".0004"]
```

This looks like something out of my son's old 3rd Grade (core curriculum) Math book!